# Basis for $M_k(\Gamma(N))$ with Fourier coeffs in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_N]$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Recently i read that the space of completely holomorphic (also at the cusps) modular forms $M_k(\Gamma(N))$ possesses a basis having Fourier coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_N]$ where $\zeta_N = e^{2 \pi i / N}$.

Can somebody point out a reference for this?

I already know the following things:
At least for $k \geq 2$, $S_k(\Gamma(N))$ -- the subspace of cusp forms -- possesses a basis having Fourier coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ (see Shimura, Thm 3.52). What is missing is the Eisenstein series $G^{v}$ (see Diamond/Shurman, Thm 4.2.3). All the Fourier coiefficients except the first one do indeed lie inside $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_N]$ (up to a constant in $\mathbb{Q}$) but the constant term of the Eienstein series is (in the case that $v_1 \equiv 0 \mod N$) the term

$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}, n \equiv v_1 \mod N} \frac{1}{n^k}$

This is the Hurwitz Zeta Function up to the term $N^{-k}$. The question here is: is this value in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_N]$ (up to some denominator) or is there a completely different way to see that such a basis with Fourier coeffs in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_N]$ exists?

Note that i am aware of this post: [Is there a Miller basis for M_k(N)?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78043/is-there-a-miller-basis-for-m-kn) but i was not able to locate the result in these books.

best and thanks!

Fabian Werner

Comment: I guess you mean the value divided by $\pi^k$ ?

Comment: Which value? You mean in the comment on the Hurwitz Zeta function?

Comment: Yes, I mean the value of the Hurwitz zeta function appearing in your question.

Comment: (For $N=1$, the sum above is $\pi^2/3$, so I think one has to divide by $\pi^k$ to get an algebraic value.)

Comment: Ooops... you are completely right. The Eisenstein series itself cannot be normalized (i.e. one cannot simply multiply the series and get something that has coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_N]$). Humm... maybe it is not a good idea to split off the cusp forms first. There must be some other reason for this to hold...

Comment: Fabian, don't forget that the higher Fourier coefficients are all multiplied by $\pi^k$ (look at the definition of $C_k$ in Diamond/Shurman Theorem 4.2.3). 

Comment: (So, in fact, the Eisenstein series can be normalized.)

Comment: Ok, i overlooked the $C_k$ but the question is: what is known about the value of this function for $N \neq 1$? (i.e. why can i always divide by $\pi^k$ and get some nice number?)

Comment: Fabian, I actually don't know any better methods than those Francois mentions in his answer. But, there is a general principle that the zero-th term in the Fourier expansion of a modular form lies in the field generated by the higher Fourier coefficients (see, e.g., http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/rationality_principle.pdf), so I knew it had to work even if I didn't know how!

Comment: @BR: please post this as an answer. This is really cool!!

Comment: Here is the reference to the rationality principle used by Klingen (in the more general context of Hilbert modular forms) : http://ams.u-strasbg.fr/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=klingen&s5=dedekind*&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=2&mx-pid=133304 (page 266). Note that in order to apply it here, you will need to know that $M_k(\Gamma(N))$ admits a basis having *all* Fourier coefficients in $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_N)$, so this is a little bit circular...

Comment: Sorry, the Mathscinet link did not parse, here is a direct link to the article : http://www.umpa.ens-lyon.fr/~brunault/klingen.pdf

Comment: (The rationality principle is mentioned at the bottom of page 266.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The constant term of the Eisenstein series $G_k^{0,v}$ in Diamond-Shurman is, up to a factor $N^k$, given by

$$\zeta(k,\frac{v}{N}) + (-1)^k \zeta(k,-\frac{v}{N})$$

where $\zeta(s,x) = \sum_{\substack{n \in \mathbf{Q}_{>0}, \\ n \equiv x \mod{1}}}  \frac{1}{n^s}$ is the Hurwitz zeta function.

You can prove by hand that this constant term indeed lies in $\pi^k \cdot \mathbf{Q}(\zeta_N)$. This is a tedious exercise (which I admit I haven't done) using the functional equation of the Hurwitz zeta function linking $\zeta(s,\cdot)$ and $\zeta(1-s,\cdot)$ and the fact that $\zeta(1-k,x) \in \mathbf{Q}[x]$ for any $k \geq 1$ (it is given by a Bernoulli polynomial). For these two facts see for example [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function).

The more conceptual explanation is that $\Gamma(N) \backslash (\mathcal{H} \cup \mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Q}))$ admits a canonical model $X(N)$ defined over $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_N)$ (see Shimura, *Introduction to the arithmetic theory of automorphic functions*, Chapter 6). Moreover, there is a more conceptual definition of Eisenstein series of weight $k$ as sections of $\mathcal{L}^{\otimes k}$, where $\mathcal{L}$ is a certain line bundle on $X(N)$ (defined using the universal elliptic curve over $Y(N)$). Since the cusps of $X(N)$ are rational over $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_N)$, the Fourier coefficients of these Eisenstein series belong automatically to $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_N)$. It then suffices to check that these Eisenstein series coincide with $G_k^{0,v}$ (suitably divided by $(2\pi i)^k$). One reference I know for this point of view is Kato, *$p$-adic Hodge theory and values of zeta functions of modular forms*, Astérisque 295, section 3.

Comment: @Francois: I tried the first version but unfortunately i have no idea on how to filter out one particular evaluation of the Hurwitz Zeta function in the functional relation. Was this proposed as an excercise in some book? Were there any hints or so?

Comment: (i.e. the functional equation only seems to say: if one of the values $\zeta(k, \frac{d}{N})$ is nice, so are the other ones)

Comment: @Fabian : I won't write the exercise for you, but here are some hints : take the formula given by Wikipedia and evaluate at $s=k$. On the left hand side you have the value $\zeta(1-k,m/N)$, which you know is rational (by the second fact I mentioned). And on the right hand side you have the values $\zeta(k,\cdot)$, which you're interested in. You can package all the formulas for $1 \leq m \leq N$ by saying the vector of $\zeta(1-k,m/N)$'s is some matrix times the vector of $\zeta(k,m'/N)$'s. Then it suffices to check the matrix has coefficients in $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_N)$ and is invertible.

Comment: Maybe i am completely blind but... Lets take $N=3$ and $k$ divisible by 4 then (for $c$ some constant)
$\zeta(1-k, \frac{d}{N}) = c * \sum_{v=1}^{N} cos(\frac{k\pi}{2} - \frac{2\pi d v}{N}) \zeta(k, \frac{v}{N})$
now $cos(\frac{k\pi}{2} - \frac{2\pi d v}{N}) = cos(\frac{2\pi d v}{N}) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{2\pi i dv/N} + e^{-2\pi i dv/N}) = 1/2(x^{vd} + \overline{x}^{vd})$ ($x = e^{2\pi i / 3}$) so the matrix is given by
$\begin{pmatrix} x+\overline{x} & x^2 + \overline{x}^2 & 2 \\ x^2 + \overline{x}^2 & x + \overline{x} & 2 \\ 2 & 2 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ but this matrix is clearly not invertible...

Comment: I was being somewhat sloppy. What you should consider is the vector of values $\zeta(k,v/N)+(-1)^k \zeta(k,-v/N)$, instead of $\zeta(k,v/N)$. Otherwise, you cannot get algebraic values (this is related to the following recent MO question : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/87348/sum-of-reciprocals-of-squares-of-integers-congruent-to-1-mod-3/87373#87373).

Comment: Ah, only now i have seen that the Hurwitz Zeta function only runs over positive numbers. Ok, Wikipedia tells me that the Hurwitz Zeta function is only defined by the sum for $Re(s)>0$ and $Re(x)>0$ but thats not a problem since for $s=k \in \mathbb{N}$, the sum actually converges for all $q \in \mathbb{C} \setminus -\mathbb{N}_0$ so that by the id-thm they coincide. But there is one problem: what to do with the additional $\zeta(k, -v/N)$? The functional equation does only work for positive rationals, right?

Comment: It depends how you define the Hurwitz zeta function. In my answer $\zeta(s,x)$ depends only on $x \mod{1}$. For a given rational $x$ this will differ only by a rational number from the other definition. If this bothers you, just replace $\zeta(k,-v/N)$ by $\zeta(k,1-v/N)$.

Comment: Ok. Still, for $N=3$ and $k$ divisible by $4$ i obtain $\zeta(1-k, v/N) + (-1)^k\zeta(1-k, (N-v)/N) = c \sum_{j} [cos(\frac{2\pi vj}{N}) + cos(\frac{2 \pi (N-v)j}{N})] \zeta(k, j/N)$ so the coefficient in the matrix is $x^{vj} + \overline{x}^{vj} + x^{vj} + \overline{x}^{vj}$ which is just two times the old coefficient, i.e. the matrix is still not invertible.

Comment: In the RHS you need to take $\zeta(k,j/N)+(-1)^k \zeta(k,-j/N)$. You also need to take these values only once (for 1 \leq j \leq N/2) otherwise the matrix will obviously not be invertible...

Comment: I am very thankful that you are so patient with me... I am sorry, now i am completely confused. Could you write down explicitely in what way i am supposed to use the functional equation?

Comment: Ok, one writes down the functional equation for $\zeta(1-k, (N-v)/N)$ does the substitution $j \mapsto N-j+1$ then $j \mapsto j-1$ and sees that the $0$-th and the $N$-th term are equal, hence
$\zeta(1-k, v/N) + (-1)^k\zeta(1-k,(N-v)/N) = c \sum \cos(\pi k/2 - 2\pi jv/N)[\zeta(k, j/N) + (-1)^k\zeta(k, (N-j)/N)]$ then, half of the term are actually equal so that one does not take the whole vector of all $t_v := \zeta(1-k, v/N) + (-1)^k\zeta(1-k, (N-v)/N))$ but rather only $t_1, ..., t_{N/2}$ which makes the matrix smaller and (i still need to check) hopefully invertible... now i got it :D

Comment: Unbelievable, when one squares the matrices they become really nice and one can really see (after doing a long computation with a lot of roots of unity) that they are invertible... this is cool. Thanks once again François!!!

Comment: @Fabian : Good ! I agree the computations were somewhat tedious. I didn't know the matrices have a nice shape after squaring, this is interesting (probably related to the fact that the functional equation can be thought of as an "involution").